# Run a command without the command line running in a new window

Tags: windows, node.js, command-line

I am trying to run a command from a node.js app that's installed on the machine. The command runs fine (it is a command to launches Tomcat). However, the command I run actually open the command line window that is launching Tomcat. Is there a way to do the same thing (run the same command to launch Tomcat) but without the command line window opening up?

Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: See this http://www.coderanch.com/t/587984/Tomcat/Tomcat-startup-bat-opens-window

Comment: I am trying to make a call inside nodejs and it is not taking >> for some reason, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't with node.js but rather with tomcat. You are probably running the wrong command.
instead of calling `catalina.bat start`, rather call `catalina.bat run`.

alternatively you can set it up as a service and call net start tomcatX